# d3-zoom mouseup event workaround

Tags: d3.js

I'm aware that starting with v4 d3-zoom swallows up certain events for some reasons I don't fully understand. I've read some [discussions](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/66#issuecomment-255175895) about this, and I know that if I `stopPropagation()` on mousedown, then the zoom behavior won't get a chance to consume the event, and mouseup will consequently fire. The problem with that is that then the zoom doesnt work.

I haven't found a workaround for the case of needing to handle the mouseup event **AND** still have the zoom work. I'm particularly interested in the dragging case only. When the user does mousedown and starts to drag the canvas, I want to change the cursor to a clenched-hand, and when the user stops dragging and lets go of the mouse I want to change the cursor back.

How is this possible to do with the new d3-zoom behavior without resorting to a timeout? 'click' event is also not an option since that doesn't fire if there's a mousemove event in between.

Comment: @pariament I have added an answer to your problem, can you please check if it answer your question. Please let me know if i am missing anything.

Comment: Why do you not use d3 v5? v5 can do [this](https://observablehq.com/@d3/drag-zoom).

Comment: @tatsuyakanemoto I was using v5 and I've seen that link it doesn't really answer the question. Ultimately, I just overlooked "end" event on zoom. I wrongly assumed it was only on drag behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am concluding from your question that you are not able to track mouseup event after dragging the canvas. If that is the case then we can use events provided by "zoom" functionality - zoomstart and zoomend.

We can simply add that to zoom behavior and track when the user starts zoom and ends zoom. And in this way we can easily change cursor property.

Please find below code snippet and working code as well. Please let me know if i am missing anything.

```js
var margin = {
    top: -5,
    right: -5,
    bottom: -5,
    left: -5
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 10])
  .on("zoom", zoomed)
  .on("start", function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].style.cursor = "grab";
  })
  .on("end", function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].style.cursor = "default";
  })

console.log(zoom.scaleExtent()[0], zoom.scaleExtent()[1]);

var drag = d3.drag()
  .subject(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .on("start", dragstarted)
  .on("drag", dragged)
  .on("end", dragended);

var slider = d3.select("body").append("p").append("input")
  .datum({})
  .attr("type", "range")
  .attr("value", zoom.scaleExtent()[0])
  .attr("min", zoom.scaleExtent()[0])
  .attr("max", zoom.scaleExtent()[1])
  .attr("step", (zoom.scaleExtent()[1] - zoom.scaleExtent()[0]) / 100)
  .on("input", slided);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
  .call(zoom);

var rect = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("pointer-events", "all");

var container = svg.append("g");

container.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(d3.range(0, width, 10))
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("x1", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("x2", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("y2", height);

container.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(d3.range(0, height, 10))
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("x1", 0)
  .attr("y1", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("x2", width)
  .attr("y2", function(d) {
    return d;
  });

dots = [{
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
}]

dot = container.append("g")
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(dots)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .call(drag);

function dottype(d) {
  d.x = +d.x;
  d.y = +d.y;
  return d;
}

function zoomed(event) {
  const currentTransform = d3.event.transform;
  container.attr("transform", currentTransform);
  slider.property("value", currentTransform.k);
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
}

function slided(d) {
  zoom.scaleTo(svg, d3.select(this).property("value"));
}
```

```css
.dot circle {
  fill: lightsteelblue;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.dot circle.dragging {
  fill: red;
  stroke: brown;
}

.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <style>

  </style>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
             .scaleExtent([1, 10])
             .on("zoom", zoomed)
             .on("start", function() {
               document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].style.cursor = "grab";
             })
             .on("end", function() {
               document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].style.cursor = "default";
             })
```

Comment: Thank you. This was fairly straight forward, I don't know how I overlooked ```start``` and ```end``` events (facepalm).

Comment: No problem buddy, it happens with all of us. Sometimes we miss small things.
Thanks for the bounty :)